# How to use two gruntfiles for the same project/folder?

Tags: gruntjs

i think i am in a special situation.

I am building a website and a mobile web-app based on the same source (with a few expectation like e.g. the index.html)

But that's why I need need two Gruntfiles to configure the build-tasks for each project separately (the site and the app).

**How can I work with two gruntfiles?**

PS: I tried to work with "grunt targets" but plugins like e.g. useminPrepare do not support targets yet.

Comment: This workaorund does the job
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838601/grunt-how-to-configure-task-for-targets-in-separate-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--gruntfile` option. Such as `grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile1.js` and `grunt --gruntfile Gruntfile2.js`.